# How to select the content inside a textbox when loading the page?

Tags: javascript, wicket, copy-paste

I'm working on an application, and I want a text field to be selected when the page is loading so that when a user uses Ctrl + v it paste the content inside the textbox. Any one knows how to do that? 
the text field is

```
<div>
    <input wicket:id="email-address" type="text" id="textbox-email" />
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set focus to your input:

```
document.forms['your_form'].elements['your_textbox'].focus();
```

For your example above:

```
document.getElementById('textbox-email').focus()
```

---

After it gained focus, you should select it:

either add this `onfocus` attribute to your inputs (better)

```
<input type="text" onfocus="this.select()" />
```

Or use this jQuery snippet (best):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#textbox-email").focus(function() { $(this).select(); } );
});
```

Pure Javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementById('textbox-email');
element.onfocus = function() {element.select();}
document.getElementById('textbox-email').focus();
```

Add the whole thing to `window.onload` or `onload` attribute of `body` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, 
this is how I tried initially, but the problem is the content inside the text field should be selected so that when i press Ctrl + v and paste it in a text editor it should get pasted the content inside the texhbox. This doesn't seems to be working when i included the above code you mentioned

Comment: @user1266343: do you want to copy the content from the textbox or do you want to paste something into the textbox? 'cause you say Ctrl+v, which is paste, not copy

Comment: Sorry, my fault, its Ctrl + C , i need to copy. thanks for ur help

Answer (score 4):

3p3r answer is of course perfectly right. If you want this to be reusable and contolled via wicket, than please check the [wicket wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Request+Focus+on+a+Specific+Form+Component).

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML5's `autofocus` attribute:

```
<input type="text" autofocus />
```

Works of course for just one field.